# JasperReport 4 on JBoss AS 5 Confliction Libs

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jboss5.x

i am using JasperReports 4.0 in a web Application that Runs on JBoss AS 5.00 CR2

when i used all jasper libraries i found jars conflicts

what should i use only from jasper's libs to solve this problem?!

Comment: please provide exception trace

Comment: not related to question, but why not to use JBoss AS 5 Final?

Comment: also tell us please, do you mean only libraries from jasperreports-4.0.0\dist, or you also copied all libraries from jasperreports-4.0.0\lib directory?

Comment: i copied all libraries under /lib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by coping all libs from jasperReports lib folder under JBossAS\server\default\lib